# C pthread printing "anomaly"

Tags: c, multithreading

I've been doing a program in C which uses a series of threads to represent cars crossing a bridge, the function I'm doing right know is the one that prints the "state" of the bridge at a certain moment, so it shows where cars (threads) are in the bridge and at which position.
The problem is this; when there is only ONE thread crossing, the function prints properly and you can see the representation of the car advancing through the bridge. But when there are more threads crossing the function gets crazy and sometimes you can see a bridge and a half, or two bridges or some other crazy things. I tried to solve it creating a pthread_mutex for that function but it wasn't the solution, or at least I'm not using it at the right place.
Every thread call this function as it advances through the bridge (the bridge is an array)
Sorry if I failed to make it clear; here is the function and thanks for your time:

```
void printBridge(bridge *pBridge, int direction) {

system("clear");
int i;

if (direction == WEST) {
    for (i = 0; i < bridgeSize; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&print);
        if (pBridge->cellState[i] == 0) { //this means the position at the array isn't occupied
            fprintf(stderr, "\t");
        } else if (pBridge->cellState[i] == 1) { //this means a car is at that position
            fprintf(stderr, "  @@@>");  //the cars are represented by @@@>
        }
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&print);
    }
} else {

    for (i = bridgeSize - 1; i >= 0; i--) { //if going the other direction
        pthread_mutex_lock(&print);
        if (pBridge->cellState[i] == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\t");
        } else if (pBridge->cellState[i] == 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "<@@@ ");

        }
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&print);
    }


}
printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
fprintf(stderr, "\n Direction= %d", pBridge->direction);

sleep(1); //because I need to see what's going on
 }
```

So...a proper print would be like this:

```
        <@@@        <@@@ 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But sometimes it gets as messy as this:

```
    <@@@ <@@@ <@@@ <@@@     
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
<@@@ <@@@ <@@@ <@@@     

 Direction= 1--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could it be because of the system("clear") being executed by many threads at a time?

**SOLVED:**

Solved calling the pthread_mutex_lock and unlock outside the function using a mutex for each position of the array ( bridge):

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pBridge->mutexBridge[i]);
    pBridge->cellState[i]=1;
    printBridge(pBridge,dir);
    pBridge->cellState[i]=0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&pPuente->mutexBridge[i]);
```

And for some reason, inside the printBridge function, wrapped the system("clear") with mutex as well:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&print);
system("clear");
pthread_mutex_unlock(&print);
```

Not doing the above gave me crazy prints. Thanks to pat for the help

Comment: probably, try putting a lock around that too.

Comment: What do you think will happen if one thread is in the middle of printing while another thread clears the screen? (And if the answer is, "I don't know", then you better make sure that doesn't happen!)

Comment: That still looks strange. If two threads are operating on different points on the bridge, they will take different locks, and still print concurrently. It also makes no sense to lock around just the clear. You want to make the clear and the printing of the entire bridge atomic across all threads, and that means you need a single lock that is held for the entirety of the clear and print.

Comment: A basic rule of thumb is that any time you read or write a shared memory location, you must be holding a murex that protects that location. A single mutex can protect multiple locations, but a location cannot be protected by separate mutexes.

Comment: I understand, I put the mutex around the system clear because it was still giving problems, and yes it makes sense what you said. Gonna talk to my teacher to see if it's ok and if I get to another solution I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

You are only locking around printing of individual cars and spaces, so, when multiple threads are printing, they will interleave the bridges on a car by car basis. You need to acquire the mutex before you start printing the bridge and release it when you are done.  In this way, threads will interleave whole bridges instead of individual cars.

Comment: You can also use `flockfile` and `funlockfile` to lock studio `FILE`s (`stderr` in this case).  Still, you need to hold the lock for the entirety of the print function.

Comment: But locking the entire function will just print "a car at a time", Am I right?

Comment: No, your function loops over the bridge size printing each car. If two threads try to print the bridge at the same time, you want one thread to finish printing before the other can start. By acquiring the lock at the start, and releasing it at the end of print bridge, you guarantee that at most one thread can be printing at a time.

Comment: Now, just because you hold the print lock doesn't mean that the bridge state isn't changing (unless you are already holding a bridge lock). If the bridge state changes while you are printing it, you might see the same car in multiple positions. This would be like trying to paint a picture of a moving subject!

Comment: gonna try to see how it works, I placed the lock/unlock as you said but got printed just a car at a time, like if they were crossing like that, but maybe it is because how I'm changing the cellState from 0 to 1 and then back to 0 when the car left that cell. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: So what does the new function look like?

Comment: I tried putting the lock/unlock before calling the function:
   pthread_mutex_lock(&print)
   printBridge();
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&print)
And also tried putting them inside the function before the loops, I went to sleep after I saw your answers so I'll be working on it later today and if I get it to work I'll share it as soon as possible

Comment: I solved it following your help, edited my question with the solution